# In a vector space over a finite field, can the orbit of a point under matrix multiplication have dependent subsets?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, finite-fields, galois-representations

Let $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ be the vector space of dimension n over the finite field of order q, $\vec{v}$ a vector in the space, and $M$ an invertible $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

We know that $M^p$ = $M^0$ = $Id$. Consider the orbit of $\vec{v}$ under repeated left multiplication by $M$. (Equivalently, under the action of the cyclic group of matrices generated by $M$ under left muliplication.) Suppose that the elements of the orbit are all unique (mod scaling), and they span $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. Is it possible that some n elements of the orbit are linearly dependent?

What if q is prime?

edit: M is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible.

Let us view $L=\Bbb{F}_{64}$ as a 6-dimensional vector space $V$ over $K=\Bbb{F}_2$. The field $L$ contains a primitive ninth root of unity $\alpha$, because $9\mid(64-1)$. Let $M:V\to V$ be multiplication by $\alpha$, so it generates a cyclic group of order nine. Let $\vec{v}=1$. The orbit consists of the powers $\alpha^i,i=0,1,\ldots,8$. These are all distinct and because $1$ is the only non-zero constant of $K$ they are also distinct mod scaling (if I understood that term correctly). They also span all of $V$ because the span of powers of $\alpha$ is a subfield, and no proper subfield of $L$ contains a primitive ninth root of unity.

But the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^6+x^3+1$, so the triplets
$$\{1,\alpha^3,\alpha^6\},\quad\{\alpha,\alpha^4,\alpha^7\},\quad\{\alpha^2,\alpha^5,\alpha^8\}$$
are all linearly dependent over $K$. Here $3<\dim_K V=6$.

Comment: If the choice of notation of parameter $p$ is meant to indicate that the order of $M$ is a prime, then we can similarly use a root of unity $\beta$ of order $31$. Its powers span the five-dimensional space $\Bbb{F}_{32}$. Its minimal polynomial can be chosen to be $x^5+x^2+1$, so again we find linearly dependent triplets within the orbit.

Comment: The example in the previous comment is kinda rare. The orbit consists of all the non-zero vectors of the space, so finding linear dependencies is given. This is because $31$ is a Mersenne prime (or $5$ is - I never remember which one of $p$ or $2^p-1$ is a Mersenne prime :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I am still a little confused. How can we be sure that multiplication by $\alpha$ is a linear transformation? How is it represented as a matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Would dependent subsets show up if p > 2?

What if the orbit has p distinct elements (mod scaling)?

Comment: @Jeffrey, it's linear basically because $\alpha(x+y)=\alpha x+\alpha y$ for all $x,y\in L$ by virtue of the field obeying the distributive law. To turn it into a matrix we need to specify a basis for $L$ over $K$. With respect to the choice $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5\}$ it looks like
$$M=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0&0&1\cr
1&0&0&0&0&0\cr
0&1&0&0&0&0\cr
0&0&1&0&0&1\cr
0&0&0&1&0&0\cr
0&0&0&0&1&0\cr}.$$

Comment: With that $M$ you can check by hand that $M^9=I_6$ and that for any non-zero vector $v$ (make your pick!), the vectors $M^jv, j=0,1,\ldots,8$ are distinct and span all of $\Bbb{F}_2^6$. Finally $v$, $M^3v$ and  $M^6v$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Do you think dependent sets are possible if the order of the field is not 2? Or if the cardinality of the orbit is p?

Comment: Sure. It is just easier to find examples over the field of two elements, because cyclotomic polynomials have factors with "random" coefficients, so over the field of two elements "half of them vanish", which is what made the above examples work.

Comment: For example a root of unity $\zeta$ of order $23$ lies in an extension of degree $n=11$ of the field $\Bbb{F}_3$. Its minimal polynomial is (with an appropriate choice of the root)
$$x^{11}+2 x^8+2 x^6+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x+2.$$
This has eight terms, so some selected sets of eight powers of $\zeta$ are linearly dependent. Yet they reside in an 11-dimensional space over $\Bbb{F}_3$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, every projective geometry over a finite field (in which the "points" are the one-dimensional subspaces) admits what is called a Singer cycle, which is a cyclic permutation that acts sharply transitively on the points.  In this case any selection of $n$ linearly dependent points lie in the same orbit.